# How to Callback Function Work in Run Time in C

Tags: c, stm32

I was looking for the some code, TFTP IAP function, in the initilize settings there is this line:

```
  udp_recv(upcb, IAP_wrq_recv_callback, args);
```

And `IAP_wrq_recv_callback` function like this.

```
static void IAP_wrq_recv_callback(void *_args, struct udp_pcb *upcb, struct pbuf *pkt_buf, 
                        const ip_addr_t *addr, u16_t port);
```

And when I receive Udp ethernet this function work although call just one time in initlizing function. How to work, callback function, how it understand receiving data ?

Comment: Please learn about *function pointers*. Using the correct type you could store a pointer to a function in a variable, and use that variable as a function and "call" it anytime.

Comment: But this function doesnt call any where except initilizing

Comment: The function isn't called in this code, but the function that you passed the function pointer to can call it. Or it can store it somewhere so it can be called later.

Comment: Are you sur that there is lot of receive (lot of send from the other side) ? And not just one time ?

Comment: That's the thing about function pointers. You can save them and call at *any* time, from *anywhere*.

Comment: If you want to know where the function is called, you need to look at implementation of `udp_recv`, not in your own code.

Comment: How is this related to "in-app-purchase"?

Comment: And how is it related to STM32?

Answer (score 0):

`udp_recv(..)` is a callback setter in LwIP. When you use this function, you pass

- pcb -  the pcb for which to set the recv callback
- recv - function pointer of the callback function
- recv_arg - additional argument to pass to the callback function

your callback function is stored in `pcb->recv` field and this `pcb->recv()` is what you looking for. It is called when proper udp datagram received. see [doc](https://www.nongnu.org/lwip/2_1_x/group__udp__raw.html#gada6d02b9a5f35e1fb2e1bc71b11e6027)